# Using a for loop with JSON object/array elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a `for()` loop with JSON data that's already been decoded, the problem is adding my loop variable (in this case `i`), to the end of the element that I'm referencing.

**For example, my JSON structure, dumped:**

```
{
    "url": "http://www.example.com",
    "rid": 1,
    "rname": "Apple iPhone 4 Rotation",
    "rmin": 90,
    "rmax": 150,
    "blank": 0,
    "geo_country_0": "GB",
    "geo_url_0": "http://en",
    "geo_country_1": "FR",
    "geo_url_1": "http://fr",
    "geo_country_2": "ES",
    "geo_url_2": "http://es"
}
```

In the case of `geo_country_` and and `geo_url_` I need to append a number, in this case the loop variable.

**My actual for loop, for a better understanding:**

```
for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                $('#geo-location').append('<div id="glt_' + i + '" class="clone"><select name="g_country['+i+']" class="glt-input-c">' + options + '</select><input type="text" name="g_url[' + i + ']" class="glt-input-c" value="' + data.geo_url_i+ '"/></div>');
                $('select[name="g_country['+i+']"').find('option[value="' + data.geo_country_i+ '"]').attr('selected','selected');
            }
```

So far I've tried:

- Encasing the the `i` like `[i]`.
- Escaping it like `\i`. (This was probably a stupid idea).
- Adding a pre-fixing `+` like, `+ data.geo_country + i +`.

What do I need to do to have `i` interpreted properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to reference `data.geo_country_?` like `data['geo_country_'+i]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you may address an object's properties in two ways:

```
var value = myobject.myproperty;
var value2 = myobject['myproperty'];
```

Using this knowledge, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
        for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            $('#geo-location').append('<div id="glt_' + i + '" class="clone"><select name="g_country['+i+']" class="glt-input-c">' + options + '</select><input type="text" name="g_url[' + i + ']" class="glt-input-c" value="' + data['geo_url_' + i] + '"/></div>');
            $('select[name="g_country['+i+']"').find('option[value="' + data['geo_country_' + i] + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
        }
```

Comment: Props, for both the edit, and the explanation. I'll accept when the timer drops :)!

Answer (score 1):

Access it like

```
data['geo_country_' + i]
```

And you should have no issues